# how to underline UILabel text - iPhone App

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [underline text in UIlabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711297/underline-text-in-uilabel)

I want to underline the `UILabel` text as **hyperlink**

```
UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 220.0, 160.0, 30.0)];
myLabel.text = @"click here";
```

How can i make the above string to be underlined ?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Create a UIView with a height of 1 and a background color of black, and stick it below the label. Alternatively, you can use CoreText to render an attributed string with an underline, though that requires a bit more work.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to subclass the UILabel and do the drawing in

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
   // Do underlined drawing here...
}
```

Comment: can you pls provide me a sample..

Comment: @iPhonegal click on my link - I posted full code there.