# IOS: string stressed and bold

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, bold

I have an array of labels

```
[labelsArray objectAtIndex:1] ????
```

I want to change label text style to bold and stressed. How can I do that?

Comment: I think you cant make string bold. What do you want to do ?

Comment: excuse me it's an array of label

Comment: Nobody knows what you mean by stressed; do you mean inset?

Comment: excuse me...I would say underlined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand what you mean by stressed but if you want to make it bold you can write:

```
UILabel *label = [labelArray objectAtIndex:1];
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:18];
```

The size and font type is ofcourse up to you.
Here are the list: http://www.prepressure.com/fonts/basics/ios-4-fonts

EDIT for comment:
I have never done that, but after some searching I found this post at stackoverflow. You may try that, but there is no "built-in" function for this as far I know.

[Underline text in UIlabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711297/underline-text-in-uilabel/2711587#2711587)

Answer (score 1):

If there are different fonts in labels, that you don't know you can try this:

```
NSInteger i = 0;
for ( ... )
{
    UILabel *label = [labelArray objectAtIndex:i];
    UIFont *oldFont = label.font;
    NSString *fontName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-BoldItalic", oldFont.fontName];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:oldFont.pointSize];
}
```

Hope this'll help!