# Underline and Strikethrough on iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uifont

I'm new to iOS/Objective-c and trying to allow the use to use underline and strike-thought text annotation but here is not a native font with this feature any way to add some kind of attribute?

```
NSDictionary *arial = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"ArialMT", [NSNumber numberWithInt:TextAnnotationFontStyleNone],
                                   @"Arial-BoldMT", [NSNumber numberWithInt:TextAnnotationStyleBold],
                                   @"Arial-ItalicMT", [NSNumber numberWithInt:TextAnnotationStyleItalic],
                                   @"Arial-BoldItalicMT", [NSNumber numberWithInt:TextAnnotationStyleBold | TextAnnotationStyleItalic],
                                   @"Arial-BoldMT", [NSNumber numberWithInt:TextAnnotationStyleUnderline], // ANY WAY TO ADD ANYTHING HERE TO MAKE IT UNDERLINE???
nil];
```

Comment: No easy way to do this. Check out this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777570/text-underline-in-iphone

Comment: NSAttributedString will give you underlining but only under iOS 6.

Answer (score 1):

Through `NSFont` you can control only font weight (i.e. bold it or not). Underlined and strike-through attributes are controlled via `NSAttributedString` (`NSMutableAttributedString`).

Answer (score 0):

For underline and Strikethrough the texts in iOS you could use AttributedString.
But AttributedString ffeature is achieved on iOS 6 version and not in lower versions.

For iOS lower than iOS-6  you can use ZAttributedStrings for underlining, strikethorugh or managing extra font effects.

There is a sample project code of iOS using ZAttributedString

Check this link of GitHub [ZattributedString](https://github.com/zynga/FontLabel)