# iPhone - Create underlined UIFont?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, underline, uifont

I already have a font object, I want to add `underlined` attribute to it without having to specify a font name.

I need to do think either using `UIFont`, or `CTFont`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no built-in support for underline, because that's not part of the font. It's drawn separately. See this SO thread for implementation details:

[Underline Text in UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711297/underline-text-in-uilabel)