# iPhone : Underline Text

Tags: iphone

Is there appeared easy way to underline text in iOS 4 ?? In IB maybe ? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Be more specific of what you want to do.

Comment: I definitely not agree with you. Question is clear...

Comment: possible duplicate of [underline text in UIlabel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711297/underline-text-in-uilabel)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot underline text.

You can "fake" it though by (for example) placing an UImageView or a regular View just underneath with the same color as your text. You can use strike-through etc, but cannot underline.

**Edit:**
You could use this approach to underline your UILabel though. You could namely use a custom `UILabel`. So you could create some class like `CUILabel` that inherits `UILabel` and replace its `drawRect` method in the `@implementation` section with the following:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
  CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 0.0f/255.0f, 0.0f/255.0f, 255.0f/255.0f, 1.0f); // Your underline color
  CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 1.0f);

  UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0f];
  CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(MAXFLOAT, MAXFLOAT);
  CGSize labelSize;
  labelSize = [self.text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];  

  CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, 0, self.bounds.size.height - 1);
  CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, labelSize.width + 10, self.bounds.size.height - 1);

  CGContextStrokePath(ctx);

  [super drawRect:rect];  
}
```

Comment: he can underline. by subclass uilabel

Answer (score 3):

Just subclass UILabel and in drawRect after you draw your text just draw an simple line under the text. Take a look at [StrikeUILabel](https://github.com/terentealex/StrikeUILabel) it have some bugs in it but you can start from that class.

Answer (score 0):

NSMutableAttributedString/NSAttributedString allows you to create text with various rich attributes like font,color,type styles (including underline). For generic details follow this link..

[Introduction to Attributed String Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/AttributedStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000036i)

Specific to underline of text, this link may help..
[Changing an Attributed String](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextAttributes/ChangingAttrStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000162)

Comment: Unlike Mac OS X, there is no facility for drawing attributed strings in iOS.

Comment: IOS 6 now has attributed strings:
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15328704/how-can-i-underline-text-in-ios-6

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes i prefer to use UILabel as Underline with background of Underline color, no text, height 1 or 2 pixel and width as equal to Text to be underline...