# How can I underline text in iOS 6?

Tags: ios, objective-c, string

I am trying to underline some text in a label. However, I do't know how to get the range of the entire text in the label. This is what I have so far:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *mat = [self.tableLabel.attributedText mutableCopy];
[mat addAttributes:@{NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle)} range://??];
self.tableLabel.attributedText = mat;
```

What should I put for the range?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711297/underline-text-in-uilabel

Answer (score 22):

For the range you may want to use:

```
NSMakeRange (0, mat.length);
```

Like this:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *mat = [self.tableLabel.attributedText mutableCopy];
[mat addAttributes:@{NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle)} range:NSMakeRange (0, mat.length)];
self.tableLabel.attributedText = mat;
```

Comment: NSMakeRange() is arguably better as it doesn't rely on C99's implicit literals which have some issues.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString =[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:strComplete];

[attributedString addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName
                         value:@(NSUnderlineStyleSingle)
                         range:[strComplete rangeOfString:strFirst]];

[attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                         value:[UIColor redColor]
                         range:[strComplete rangeOfString:strSecond]];


cell.textLabel.attributedText = attributedString;
```

Comment: Please note that code only answers are discouraged.