# How can I create a UILabel with strikethrough text?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uilabel, strikethrough

I want to create a `UILabel` in which the text is like this

[image]

How can I do this? When the text is small, the line should also be small.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10550732/font-with-strike-through-it

Comment: If you only need iOS 6 support then you can do this with an `NSAttributedString` and the `UILabel attributedText` property.

Comment: is it possible to unstrike the button text

Answer (score 264, accepted):

**SWIFT 5 UPDATE CODE**

```
let attributeString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Your Text")
    attributeString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle, value: 2, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributeString.length))
```

then:

```
yourLabel.attributedText = attributeString
```

**To make some part of string to strike then provide range**

```
let somePartStringRange = (yourStringHere as NSString).range(of: "Text")
attributeString.addAttribute(NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName, value: 2, range: somePartStringRange)
```

---

**Objective-C**

In **iOS 6.0 >** `UILabel` supports `NSAttributedString`

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributeString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Your String here"];
[attributeString addAttribute:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName
                        value:@2
                        range:NSMakeRange(0, [attributeString length])];
```

**Swift**

```
let attributeString: NSMutableAttributedString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Your String here")
attributeString.addAttribute(NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName, value: 2, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))
```

**Definition** :

```
- (void)addAttribute:(NSString *)name value:(id)value range:(NSRange)aRange
```

`Parameters List:`

**name** : A string specifying the attribute name. Attribute keys can be supplied by another framework or can be custom ones you define. For information about where to find the system-supplied attribute keys, see the overview section in NSAttributedString Class Reference.

**value** : The attribute value associated with name.

**aRange** : The range of characters to which the specified attribute/value pair applies.

Then

```
yourLabel.attributedText = attributeString;
```

---

For `lesser than iOS 6.0 versions` you need `3-rd party component` to do this.
One of them is [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel), another is [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel).

Comment: For iOS 5.1.1 lesser version how can I use 3 party attributed Label to display attributed text: ?

Comment: Can You suggest a good Toutorial? The link which you provided is little bit difficult to understand.. :(

Comment: Can you explain what I should do for creating a third party attributed Label for ios

Comment: What is @2? Magic number?

Comment: I guess you forgot to commit that. You should use a proper value from NSUnderlineStyle instead of @2. I am little bit pedantic here.

Comment: It can be expressed shorter, without the need for mutability: ```[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"string" attributes:@{NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName : @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle)}];```

Comment: For me it doesn't work if I try to strikethrough only part of string, but not all. Is this intended? And is it possible to still make it strikethrough just one word inside long text?

Comment: Why NSAttributedStringKey.strikethroughStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue is not working in swift 4 ?

Comment: How to get striked on the center of the label?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43074652/1359088) thread if you have issues with the strikethrough appearing.

Answer (score 61):

In Swift, using the single strikethrough line style:

```swift
let attributedText = NSAttributedString(
    string: "Label Text",
    attributes: [.strikethroughStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue]
)
label.attributedText = attributedText
```

Additional strikethrough styles (**Remember to use the .rawValue**):

- `.none`
- `.single`
- `.thick`
- `.double`

Strikethrough patterns (to be OR-ed with the style):

- `.patternDot`
- `.patternDash`
- `.patternDashDot`
- `.patternDashDotDot`

Specify that the strikethrough should only be applied across words (not spaces):

- `.byWord`

Comment: Up voted for using the right constant instead of a number

Answer (score 38):

Strikethrough in Swift 5.0

```
let attributeString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Your Text")
attributeString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle,
                                     value: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue,
                                         range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))
self.yourLabel.attributedText = attributeString
```

It worked for me like a charm.

Use it as extension

```
extension String {
    func strikeThrough() -> NSAttributedString {
        let attributeString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: self)
        attributeString.addAttribute(
            NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle,
               value: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue,
                   range:NSMakeRange(0,attributeString.length))
        return attributeString
    }
}
```

Call like this

```
myLabel.attributedText = "my string".strikeThrough()
```

UILabel extension for strikethrough Enable/Disable.

```
extension UILabel {

func strikeThrough(_ isStrikeThrough:Bool) {
    if isStrikeThrough {
        if let lblText = self.text {
            let attributeString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: lblText)
            attributeString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle, value: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue, range: NSMakeRange(0,attributeString.length))
            self.attributedText = attributeString
        }
    } else {
        if let attributedStringText = self.attributedText {
            let txt = attributedStringText.string
            self.attributedText = nil
            self.text = txt
            return
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Use it like this :

```
   yourLabel.strikeThrough(btn.isSelected) // true OR false
```

Comment: Do you happen to know a solution to StrikeThrough not being removed? Similar to https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/121366

Answer (score 36):

I prefer `NSAttributedString` rather than `NSMutableAttributedString` for this simple case:

```
NSAttributedString * title =
    [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"$198"
                                    attributes:@{NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName:@(NSUnderlineStyleSingle)}];
[label setAttributedText:title];
```

---

Constants for specifying both the `NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName` and `NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName` attributes of an attributed string:

```
typedef enum : NSInteger {  
  NSUnderlineStyleNone = 0x00,  
  NSUnderlineStyleSingle = 0x01,  
  NSUnderlineStyleThick = 0x02,  
  NSUnderlineStyleDouble = 0x09,  
  NSUnderlinePatternSolid = 0x0000,  
  NSUnderlinePatternDot = 0x0100,  
  NSUnderlinePatternDash = 0x0200,  
  NSUnderlinePatternDashDot = 0x0300,  
  NSUnderlinePatternDashDotDot = 0x0400,  
  NSUnderlineByWord = 0x8000  
} NSUnderlineStyle;
```

Answer (score 23):

**SWIFT CODE**

```
let attributeString: NSMutableAttributedString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Your Text")
    attributeString.addAttribute(NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName, value: 2, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))
```

then:

```
yourLabel.attributedText = attributeString
```

Thanks to [Prince answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13133178/1311093) ;)

Answer (score 16):

**SWIFT 4**

```
    let attributeString: NSMutableAttributedString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Your Text Goes Here")
    attributeString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.strikethroughStyle, value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))
    self.lbl_productPrice.attributedText = attributeString
```

Other method is to used String Extension
**Extension**

```
extension String{
    func strikeThrough()->NSAttributedString{
        let attributeString: NSMutableAttributedString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: self)
        attributeString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.strikethroughStyle, value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))
        return attributeString
    }
}
```

**Calling the function :** Used it like so

```
testUILabel.attributedText = "Your Text Goes Here!".strikeThrough()
```

**Credit to @Yahya** *- update Dec 2017*
**Credit to @kuzdu** *- update Aug 2018*

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Purnendu roy's answer work for me. The only difference is that you pass in `value` `0` and Purnendu roy pass `value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue`

Comment: @kuzdu funny thing that my answer was back in dec 2017 it works back then he just copied my code and add up NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue ^-^ But no problem i will update this answer just to make you happy

Answer (score 10):

Strike out UILabel text in Swift iOS. PLease try this it's working for me

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"12345")
                      attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.baselineOffset, value: 0, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))
                      attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.strikethroughStyle, value: NSNumber(value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleThick.rawValue), range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))
                      attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.strikethroughColor, value: UIColor.gray, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))

 yourLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

You can change your  "strikethroughStyle" like styleSingle, styleThick,styleDouble
[image]

Answer (score 9):

You can do it in IOS 6 using NSMutableAttributedString.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attString=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"$198"];
[attString addAttribute:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] range:NSMakeRange(0,[attString length])];
yourLabel.attributedText = attString;
```

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 5**

```
extension String {

  /// Apply strike font on text
  func strikeThrough() -> NSAttributedString {
    let attributeString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self)
    attributeString.addAttribute(
      NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle,
      value: 1,
      range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributeString.length))

      return attributeString
     }
   }
```

Example:

```
someLabel.attributedText = someText.strikeThrough()
```

Comment: Difference between value: 1 and value: 2

Comment: @iOS value is the thickness of the line that strikethrough the text. The larger the value, the thicker the line that crosses out the text

Comment: @VladimirPchelyakov No. The value corresponds to `NSUnderlineStyle` rawValue (NSNumber). 1 = single, 2 = thick, 9 = double, and there is many other styles between thick and double

Answer (score 6):

**Swift5 UILabel Extension**. Removing strikethrough sometimes doesn't work. Use this code in that case.

```
extension UILabel {
    func strikeThrough(_ isStrikeThrough: Bool = true) {
        guard let text = self.text else {
            return
        }
        
        if isStrikeThrough {
            let attributeString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
            attributeString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle, value: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue, range: NSMakeRange(0,attributeString.length))
            self.attributedText = attributeString
        } else {
            let attributeString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
            attributeString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle, value: [], range: NSMakeRange(0,attributeString.length))
            self.attributedText = attributeString
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For anyone looking on how to do this in a tableview cell (Swift) you have to set the .attributeText like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TheCell")!

    let attributeString: NSMutableAttributedString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: message)
    attributeString.addAttribute(NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName, value: 2, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))

    cell.textLabel?.attributedText =  attributeString

    return cell
    }
```

If you want to remove the strikethrough do this otherwise it will stick around!:

```
cell.textLabel?.attributedText =  nil
```

Answer (score 3):

I might be late to the party.

Anyway, I am aware about the `NSMutableAttributedString` but recently I achieved the same functionality with slightly different approach.

- I added the UIView with height = 1.
- Matched the leading and trailing constraints of the UIView with the label's leading and trailing constraints
- Aligned the UIView at centre of the Label

After following all the above steps my Label, UIView and its constraints were looking like below image.

[image]

Comment: smart solution 

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4 and 5**

```
extension NSAttributedString {

    /// Returns a new instance of NSAttributedString with same contents and attributes with strike through added.
     /// - Parameter style: value for style you wish to assign to the text.
     /// - Returns: a new instance of NSAttributedString with given strike through.
     func withStrikeThrough(_ style: Int = 1) -> NSAttributedString {
         let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: self)
         attributedString.addAttribute(.strikethroughStyle,
                                       value: style,
                                       range: NSRange(location: 0, length: string.count))
         return NSAttributedString(attributedString: attributedString)
     }
}
```

**Example**

```
let example = NSAttributedString(string: "440").withStrikeThrough(1)
myLabel.attributedText = example
```

**Results**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Use below code**

```
NSString* strPrice = @"£399.95";

NSMutableAttributedString *titleString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:strPrice];

[finalString addAttribute: NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInteger: NSUnderlineStyleSingle] range: NSMakeRange(0, [titleString length])];
self.lblOldPrice.attributedText = finalString;
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4.2**

```
let attributeString: NSMutableAttributedString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: product.price)

attributeString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle, value: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))

lblPrice.attributedText = attributeString
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5 - short version

```swift
let attributedText = NSAttributedString(
    string: "Label Text",
    attributes: [.strikethroughStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue]
)

yourLabel.attributedText = attributedText
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the text property to attributed and select the text and right click to get the font property. Click on the strikethrough.
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

On iOS 10.3 has an issue on rendering strikethrough line fixes by Adding a NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName, as explained here, to the attributed string brings back the strikethrough line. Overriding drawText:in: can be slow especially on Collection View or Table View Cells.

One sol - Add view to render a line.

Second sol -

````
attributeString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle, value: 2, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))
attributeString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.baselineOffset, value: 2, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))```
````

Answer (score 0):

For those who face issue with multi line text strike

```
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: item.name!)
    //necessary if UILabel text is multilines
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName, value: 0, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))
     attributedString.addAttribute(NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName, value: NSNumber(value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue), range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSStrikethroughColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.darkGray, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))

    cell.lblName.attributedText = attributedString
```

Answer (score 0):

**Create String extension and add below method**

```
static func makeSlashText(_ text:String) -> NSAttributedString {


 let attributeString: NSMutableAttributedString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
        attributeString.addAttribute(NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName, value: 2, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))

return attributeString 

}
```

then use for your label like this

```
yourLabel.attributedText = String.makeSlashText("Hello World!")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the one you can use in Swift 4 because NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName has been changed to NSAttributedStringKey.strikethroughStyle

```
let attributeString: NSMutableAttributedString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Your Text")

attributeString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.strikethroughStyle, value: 2, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))

self.lbl.attributedText = attributeString
```