# Target a cell - Strikethrough to Mark Task Item as Complete - Swift 3

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I am a total newbie to Swift and XCode. I am in the process of creating a to do list application.  I am attempting to mark a task as complete when a user swipes the cell in the table and clicks a "complete" button, but I am having difficulty targeting a specific table cell in order to do this.  I found this example: [UILabel with text struck through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13133014/uilabel-with-text-struck-through) (see comment by MicroR), which helped me actually figure out how to do a strikethrough on a given piece of text, and I have this basic idea of strikethrough working if I just add it in when I create my table cells in my cellForRowAtIndexPath function.  The issue is that I would like to only mark a task as complete when a user clicks the complete button after swiping on that specific cell in the table.  I need some help with the code for targeting a cell after the user pushes the "complete" button (this function is the last one in the code below, but I included the rest of the code in this function for clarity).  Thank you!

Here is the code that allows a strikethrough to happen when I put it in my cellForRowatIndexPath function

```
let attributeString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: message)
attributeString.addAttribute(NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName, value: 2, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))
```

Here is my code:

```
// I pull in fake data right now from another function - sentData1 contains my task item.
var sentData1:String!
var sentData2:String!
var sentData3:String!
var sentData4:String!
var sentData5:String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    self.navigationItem.title = sentData5
}

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return self.section [section]
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return self.section.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Task", for: indexPath)

    cell.selectionStyle = .none

    switch (indexPath.section)
    {
    case 0:
        cell.textLabel?.text = sentData1
    case 1:
        cell.textLabel?.text = sentData2
    case 2:
        cell.textLabel?.text = sentData3
    case 3:
        cell.textLabel?.text = sentData4
    default:
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Other"

    }
    return cell     
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Delete") { action, index in
        print("delete button tapped")
    }
    delete.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 27/255, green: 124/255, blue: 150/255, alpha: 1.0)

    let edit = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Edit") { action, index in
        print("edit button tapped")
    }
    edit.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 130/255, green: 208/255, blue: 216/255, alpha: 1.0)

    let markComplete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Complete") { action, index in
        // this is where I want to target the cell!
        print("complete button tapped")

    }
    markComplete.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 66/255, blue: 89/255, alpha: 1.0)
    return [edit, delete, markComplete]
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool
{
    return true
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

}
```

Comment: i think you should manage lastSelectedIndexPath variable

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - I don't see that in the documentation.  Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

:) 
I am  a total newbie to Swift and XCode too..
My english is no good too :)
but if i understood you. 
I think that the answer to your question is..:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]?
    {   
        let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Delete") { action, index in
            self.Apertou_Botao(pIndice: indexPath.row, pTexto: "Apertou Deletar")
        }
        delete.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 27/255, green: 124/255, blue: 150/255, alpha: 1.0)
 return [delete]
}

func Apertou_Botao(pIndice : Int , pTexto : String)
    {
        print("\(pTexto) indice Clicado..: \(pIndice)");
    }
}
```