# UITextView.attributedString text gets replaced with strikethrough

Tags: ios, swift, textview, nsattributedstring

**Issue**

Setting

`cell.textView.attributedText = NSAttributedString.strikeThroughText("Any sort of text Goes Here")`

inside of a UITableViewCell causes the text itself to be replaced with a strikethrough the length of the actual text. The `textView` still holds the correct String value, but the text itself is not visible, only the strikethrough.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    cell.textView.attributedText = NSAttributedString.strikeThroughText(self.tasks[indexPath.row].name!)

    return cell
}

// Note - tableview is black, so the white text should be visible
extension NSAttributedString {
  static func strikeThroughText(_ text: String ) -> NSAttributedString {
    let attributeString: NSMutableAttributedString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
    attributeString.addAttribute(NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName, value: 2, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))
    attributeString.addAttribute(NSStrikethroughColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.white, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))
    return attributeString
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

**Note**

I am able to use this code correctly on a UILabel.

**Question**

How to correctly perform strikethrough on a UITextView's text

Comment: You are adding a color attribute to turn the strikethrough white, but since you never set the color of the text it'll default to black, right?  Don't you just need to set the text color to white too?

Comment: ah, Lol it worked. Hadn't realized it would default the text since it didn't do that on a UILabel

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13133014/uilabel-with-text-struck-through

Comment: @ChetanHedamba not sure what thats for but ok