# How Do I create an "underline" text in UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel

I gotta create a UITableView Cell with a "line" passing through. Do you guys know how to do it? It will be a price tag, so I want to say something like: "Old price and now with 50% OFF". So, the "old price" should be crossed.

**UI Code**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "topSoldCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    let content = self.dataTopSold[indexPath.item]
    cell.labelNomeTopSell.text = content.nome
    cell.imageViewTopSell.setImage(url: content.urlImagem, placeholder: "")
    cell.labelPrecoDe.text = "R$ \(content.precoDe)"
    cell.labelPrecoPor.text = "R$ 119.99"
    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueId", sender:self.dataTopSold[indexPath.row])

    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

         if segue.identifier == "segueId" {

        let des = segue.destination as! TelaDetalheProdutos

        des.stringNomeeDesc = sender as! Top10
    }
}
```

Comment: show some ui or code

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13133014/uilabel-with-text-struck-through

Comment: I’ve tried all methods on this post. However, none of them worked for me once I want it on my UITableview Cell @AkshaysinghYaduvanshi

Comment: @Anbu.karthik Hello! I just updated the post containing the UICode. Could you check, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case

`It will be a price tag, so I want to say something like: "Old price and now with 50% OFF". So, the "old price" should be crossed.`

You can using attributed string to support it.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "topSoldCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    let content = self.dataTopSold[indexPath.item]
    cell.labelNomeTopSell.text = content.nome
    cell.imageViewTopSell.setImage(url: content.urlImagem, placeholder: "")
    let oldPrice = "R$ \(content.precoDe)"
    let promotionString = oldPrice + " and now with 50% OFF"
    let attributedStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: promotionString)
    let crossAttr = [NSAttributedStringKey.strikethroughStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue]
    attributedStr.addAttributes(crossAttr, range: NSMakeRange(0, oldPrice.count))
    cell.labelPrecoDe.text = attributedStr
    cell.labelPrecoPor.text = "R$ 119.99"
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Hello! Oh, I guess I wrote wrong. When I said “old price” I meant like literally the old product price. I gotta do that with a UILabel on my UITabeviewCell that receives the old product price. Did you get me?

Comment: @BrunoVavretchek change the ''old price" to "\(your_old_price)" and yourLabel to your UITableviewCell's label

Comment: So, “old price” would receive the cell.labelOldPrice.text?. Will that works?

Comment: Could you look at my code and provide me an example, please?

Comment: @BrunoVavretchek : Updated my code, can you check it?

Answer (score 0):

As **Old price** is static content and also at first place in label. So you can take line image and put on Label at first place so it will look like on **Old price** . Now you can hide/show image according to your need.

If you have to give underline to some text in label then simply put that string in TextEdit. Edit their as you want. And copy to label text by setting label style Plain to Attributed.

Hope so this work for you