# create custom segmentControl

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm trying to create a rather custom segmentControl. What is the easiest way to create such below. with just text and a border line the selected?

[image]

Comment: use custom **UIButton**, in this place of **SegmentControl**

Comment: so just make 4 uibuttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Choice -1**

ya just created 4 buttons and create the one common method , inside the method assign the tag for each button for identify which button is selected , on that selected button change the `TextColor` and use use [Underline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711297/underline-text-in-uilabel),else button are another color

**Choice -2**

ya just created 4 buttons and create the one common method , inside the method assign the tag for each button for identify which button is selected , on that selected button change the `Image` in `UIControlStateNormal`  else no selection Button use normal Text or another Image

Comment: it is optimize your work and at the same time easy to handle

Answer (score 0):

You can create buttons and give tag to each of them,which will identify which button has been selected.Whenever a button is marked as selected change the state to .selected with its image.

Answer (score 0):

You can make fastens and offer tag to each of them,which will recognize which catch has been selected. Whenever a catch is set apart as chosen change the state to .selected with its image.