# How to underline single words in a label in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, label, xamarin.forms, underline

I would like to make underline text of label in Xamarin.Forms. I could not find any proper solution for this. One thing I found that there is no underline property for the text in a in Xamarin, so we could add a `BoxView` for the line instead like this:

```
<StackLayout  Grid.Row="0" Padding="0" VerticalOptions="Center">
    <Label Text="Terms and Conditions" />
    <BoxView BackgroundColor="White" HeightRequest="1" Margin="0,-8,0,0" />
</StackLayout>
```

But this is also not an appropriate solution as it will draw line to the whole `StackView`. I would like to underline only parts of text like the word "Terms" in above code.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [Effects](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/effects/creating/) for this.

Create a `UnderlineEffect` using:

**Android**

```
var tv = (TextView)Control;
tv.PaintFlags = tv.PaintFlags | PaintFlags.UnderlineText;
```

**iOS**

You have to use Mutable String as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19630376/1489968

**Edit**

I've written a blog post. Enjoy: http://smstuebe.de/2016/08/29/underlinedlabel.xamarin.forms/

Comment: sorry i am new to xamarin .i didnt get it your point.could you please elobarate?

Comment: I've linked the tutorial. Please read it and try to think about how this works with a Label.

Comment: great..blog post...its very big help...thank you for sparing your such precious time..I am really very thankful :)

Comment: Its a very big help

Comment: Thanks @Sven-MichaelStübe. I have to make an app that also supports UWP. How would you do it there?

Comment: @Sven-MichaelStübe  the git link is not working. I found it by googling it.

Comment: @Sven-MichaelStübe - Thank you your article was very helpful!  Question:  My xaml recognizes this namespace:
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UnderlineLabel.Droid"
But not: 
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UnderlineLabel"
I'm sure I made an error somewhere.  Does this ring a bell to you?

Comment: Can you tell pls how to underline in xamarin mac?

Comment: Should be similar to iOS, because the most APIs are the same, but in a different namespace.