# UIButton "setAttributedTitle" display "(null)"

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, nsattributedstring

The button displays "(null)" if using "setAttributedTitle". It can display the right string with no attributes if using "setTitle".

Any idea how to correctly display the attributed one? Why can it be "null"?

```
// Set current bar button attributes
NSMutableAttributedString *currentBarAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
[currentBarAttributedString appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"REQUEST\n"
                                                                         attributes:@{NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleNone)}]];
[currentBarAttributedString appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"EQUIPMENT"
                                                                         attributes:@{NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle)}]];
// Initialize buttons and set titles
UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button1 setAttributedTitle:currentBarAttributedString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Does `currentBarAttributedString` logs the correct value?

Comment: @Larme Yes, if prints it as a String, it can log the correct value. But on screen display, it is "(null)".

Comment: try set the title first and then set the attributed title.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri It can display the string but without the underline. So, "setAttributedString" not update the title? Do you think there is anything wrong with the way I set the "attributedString"?

Comment: Pls refer the anser http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711297/underline-text-in-uilabel

Comment: your code is just fine. set appropriate width and height to button.